# Modify the function variables from inner function in python

Tags: python, function, variables, scope

It's ok to get and print the outer function variable `a`

```
def outer():
    a = 1
    def inner():
        print a
```

It's also ok to get the outer function array `a` and append something

```
def outer():
    a = []
    def inner():
        a.append(1)
        print a
```

However, it caused some trouble when I tried to increase the integer:

```
def outer():
    a = 1
    def inner():
        a += 1 #or a = a + 1
        print a

>> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

Why does this happen and how can I achieve my goal (increase the integer)?

Comment: Of course, you could also pass a to inner from outer.

Comment: @sberry: That will not allow what he's trying to do, since it will create a new local variable inside `inner`, changes to which will not be reflected in `outer`.

Comment: Right, unless it is returned, or the OP only has use of `a` within inner anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workaround for Python 2:

```
def outer():
    a = [1]
    def inner():
        a[0] += 1
        print a[0]
```

Answer (score 5):

In Python 3 you can do this with the `nonlocal` keyword.  Do `nonlocal a` at the beginning of `inner` to mark `a` as nonlocal.

In Python 2 it is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

A generally cleaner way to do this would be:

```
def outer():
    a = 1
    def inner(b):
        b += 1
        return b
    a = inner(a)
```

Python allows a lot, but non-local variables can be generally considered as "dirty" (without going into details here).