# How to change outer function local variables from an inner function in Python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Modify the function variables frominner function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985671/modify-the-function-variables-frominner-function-in-python)

Say I have this python code

```
def f():
    x=2
    def y():
        x+=3
    y()
```

this raises:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

So, how do I "modify" `local variable 'x'` from the inner function? Defining x as a global in the inner function also raised an error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`nonlocal` statement](http://docs.python.org/3.0/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal) in Python 3:

```
>>> def f():
...     x = 2
...     def y():
...         nonlocal x
...         x += 3
...         print(x)
...     y()
...     print(x)
...

>>> f()
5
5
```

In Python 2 you need to declare the variable as an attribute of the outer function to achieve the same.

```
>>> def f():
...     f.x = 2
...     def y():
...         f.x += 3
...         print(f.x)
...     y()
...     print(f.x)
...

>>> f()
5
5
```

or using we can also use a `dictionary` or a `list`:

```
>>> def f():
...     dct = {'x': 2}
...     def y():
...         dct['x'] += 3
...         print(dct['x'])
...     y()
...     print(dct['x'])
...

>>> f()
5
5
```

Comment: +1, but note that this only applies to setting a value, and hence if you have a mutable value in the outer scope, it's possible to mutate it from the inner scope.

Comment: @Lattyware That's why we can use a `dict` or `list` as well, but that looks unpythonic though.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Indeed, the other options are better unless the data structure is needed anyway.